# Can I enable back-button focus on a 3rd-party battery grip for my Nikon D610?

Tags: autofocus, camera-settings, battery-grip, nikon-d600

I have set up my camera to have back button focus. Does this not carry over to the battery grip or is there a way to set that up as well.

I have a Nikon D610 but I have a third party grip (vello brand i believe, maybe that is the issue?)

Thanks in advance if anyone knows the answer or work-around for this.

Answer (score 2):

The way every grip I've ever used has worked is that whatever particular button on the grip corresponds to a particular button on the camera will function the same way as that button on the camera body without any additional setup. Just as pressing the shutter release on the grip does the exact same thing as pressing the shutter button on the camera, if the grip includes an *AE-L:AF-L* button it should function the same way as how you have the *AE-L:AF-L* button set on the camera.

If it is not doing so, then you need to troubleshoot a little. Most of the time I have found that disconnecting the grip, checking to be sure the spring loaded connecting pins on the grip and the in the battery well of the camera are cleaned and properly aligned, reinserting the grip and wiggling it around to be sure it is in the battery well straight and pressing all the way against the contacts will go a long way to solving any problems with a button (or more) not working. Most grips also have an on/off switch. Please check to be sure it is in the *on* position.

Comment: Not seeming to work that way for me. The shutter still does the focusing and on the camera I have bbf set up. Must just be that grip I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Go into your custom settings menu and assign and scroll down until you see the "Assign MB-D15" button. Change it to "AF-ON" or whatever you want it to be.